# How to read logcat error file. How can I read and tell what my logcat below means?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

```
08-02 20:48:36.703: D/EditText(3575): nouy
08-02 20:48:36.793: I/Choreographer(3575): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-02 20:48:37.143: D/dalvikvm(3575): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1331K, 34% free 2956K/4428K, paused 4ms+59ms, total 137ms
08-02 20:48:37.353: D/AndroidRuntime(3575): Shutting down VM
08-02 20:48:37.394: W/dalvikvm(3575): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.note/com.example.note.NoteEdit}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at com.example.note.NoteEdit.populateFields(NoteEdit.java:231)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at com.example.note.NoteEdit.onCreate(NoteEdit.java:99)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: Show us the onCreate function of this activity please.

Comment: Please post the code with context for `NoteEdit.java:231` in your code.

Comment: `Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`

Comment: Your query returns no row and you attempts to access a row value at the first column.

Comment: I guess your `cursor` returning no rows. Try `yourCursorObject.moveToFirst()` and check what it returns.

Comment: @Melanina : Don't post code in a comment. Edit your original question and post the code there.

Comment: My LogCat comes from the code posted from [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024533/how-to-pass-get-text-from-userinput-edittext-and-put-into-a-textview-in-anothe)

Answer (score 2):

The output in Logcat should be read from top(in your case, `FATAL EXCEPTION: main` onwards). However, you need to find how your activity contributes to the error. In most cases(and definitely not all), you will find Logcat informing you about a line of code inside the scope of your app. This is where the exception originated:

```
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
-------->>>>>>>>>     08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at com.example.note.NoteEdit.populateFields(NoteEdit.java:231)
```

After this, the error propagates towards the top before reaching:

```
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 20:48:37.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.note/com.example.note.NoteEdit}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Another thing to be careful about: exceptions don't always occur independently. You can have several exceptions stacked up. In this case, find the exception that is thrown first(lowest in the Logcat output) and work your way to the top.